# Python 3.4 Asynchio Chat Server/Client. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp

I am working on a Python 3.4 chat asynchio server and client but I have having a little trouble porting the client to asynchio.

Here's the link for your reference.

[18.5.4.3.1. TCP echo client protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol)

My working asynchio working chat server code below:

```
import asyncio

clients = []

class SimpleChatClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        peername = transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        self.username = "{:s}:{:d}".format(*peername)
        print("connection_made: {}".format(self.username))

        for client in clients:
            client.send("{:s} connected".format(self.username))

        clients.append(self)

    def send(self, text):
        self.transport.write("{:s}\n".format(text).encode())

    def data_received(self, data):
        print("data_received: {}".format(data.decode()))

        incoming = data.decode()

        if len(incoming) == 0:
            return

        if incoming.find("/") == 0:
            parts = incoming.split()

            command = parts[0]

            print("found command block: {:s}".format(command))

            if command == "/username":
                if len(parts) != 2:
                    self.send("< command: invalid payload! Usage: /username <username>")
                    return

                print("{:s} changing username to {:s}".format(self.username, parts[1]))

                for client in clients:
                    if client != self:
                        client.send("{:s} changed username to {:s}".format(self.username, parts[1]))

                self.username = parts[1]
                self.send("< username changed")

                return

            elif command == "/whisper":
                if len(parts) < 3:
                    self.send("< command: invalid payload! Usage: /w <username> <message>")
                    return

                for client in clients:
                    if client.username == parts[1]:
                        client.send("{:s} whispered: {:s}".format(self.username, " ".join(parts[2:])))
                        return

                self.send("< command: whisper target username not found!")
                return

            elif command == "/exit":
                self.send("< command: disconnecting, bye!")
                print("client_disconnect: {:s}".format(self.username))
                self.transport.close()
                return

        for client in clients:
            if client is not self:
                client.send("{:s} wrote: {:s}".format(self.username, incoming))

    def connection_lost(self, ex):
        print("connection_lost: {}".format(self.username))
        clients.remove(self)

        for client in clients:
            client.send("{:s} disconnected".format(self.username))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("starting up..")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(SimpleChatClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    for socket in server.sockets:
        print("serving on {}".format(socket.getsockname()))

    loop.run_forever()
```

My Old working Threaded chat client code below:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

host = '127.0.0.1'
port = 8888
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))

def Listener():
    try:
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            print('>', data)
    except ConnectionAbortedError:
        pass

t = Thread(target=Listener)
t.start()

try:
    while True:
        message = input('>')
        s.send(message.encode('utf-8'))
except EOFError:
    pass
finally:
    s.close()
```

Using the link below as reference, can anyone help me modify it so that it sends messages via shell input like my old client code?

Thank you so much for any help.

[18.5.4.3.1. TCP echo client protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to broadcast messages from `STDIN` to every connected client, is that right?

Here try this:

```
import asyncio

clients = []

class SimpleChatClientProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        peername = transport.get_extra_info("peername")
        self.username = "{:s}:{:d}".format(*peername)
        print("connection_made: {}".format(self.username))

        for client in clients:
            client.send("{:s} connected".format(self.username))

        clients.append(self)

    def send(self, text):
        self.transport.write("{:s}\n".format(text).encode())

    def data_received(self, data):
        print("data_received: {}".format(data.decode()))

        incoming = data.decode()

        if len(incoming) == 0:
            return

        if incoming.find("/") == 0:
            parts = incoming.split()

            command = parts[0]

            print("found command block: {:s}".format(command))

            if command == "/username":
                if len(parts) != 2:
                    self.send("< command: invalid payload! Usage: /username <username>")
                    return

                print("{:s} changing username to {:s}".format(self.username, parts[1]))

                for client in clients:
                    if client != self:
                        client.send("{:s} changed username to {:s}".format(self.username, parts[1]))

                self.username = parts[1]
                self.send("< username changed")

                return

            elif command == "/whisper":
                if len(parts) < 3:
                    self.send("< command: invalid payload! Usage: /w <username> <message>")
                    return

                for client in clients:
                    if client.username == parts[1]:
                        client.send("{:s} whispered: {:s}".format(self.username, " ".join(parts[2:])))
                        return

                self.send("< command: whisper target username not found!")
                return

            elif command == "/exit":
                self.send("< command: disconnecting, bye!")
                print("client_disconnect: {:s}".format(self.username))
                self.transport.close()
                return

        for client in clients:
            if client is not self:
                client.send("{:s} wrote: {:s}".format(self.username, incoming))

    def connection_lost(self, ex):
        print("connection_lost: {}".format(self.username))
        clients.remove(self)

        for client in clients:
            client.send("{:s} disconnected".format(self.username))

@asyncio.coroutine
def send_from_stdin(loop):
  while True:
    message = yield from loop.run_in_executor(None, input, ">")
    for client in clients:
      client.send(message)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("starting up..")

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    coro = loop.create_server(SimpleChatClientProtocol, '127.0.0.1', 8888)
    server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

    # Start a task which reads from STDIN and pushes to clients.
    asyncio.async(send_from_stdin(loop))

    for socket in server.sockets:
        print("serving on {}".format(socket.getsockname()))

    loop.run_forever()
```

The trick is to async-ize the `input` function by running it in a thread (this is what `run_in_executor` does). This way when you are waiting for data from `STDIN` you don't block the entire loop.